# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function in Django admain page

Tags: javascript, python, django

I was using Django 1.9 to build my comment-check application, but I suddenly found parts of CSS/javascript didn't display on the Django admin page while I was on the adjustment about urls and views.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cqdc.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXFJz.jpg)
As you can see, all admin pages like picture one except the detail content pages like picture two works well. And in the content pages, Chrome developer tool console show these messages

```
RelatedObjectLookups.js:160 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at RelatedObjectLookups.js:160
at RelatedObjectLookups.js:189
(anonymous) @RelatedObjectLookups.js:160
(anonymous) @RelatedObjectLookups.js:189
```

For sure, I don't want to paste the code from RelatedObjectLookups.js becasue I never edited any statements in this js file(maybe). This file's location is here by default:

```
myapp\static\admin\js\admin
```

I didn't get any 404 status code or other error response from the server. Most importantly, when I tried to check whether it was the specific case in this app so I opened my other django projects admin pages, this problem still persisted. Even though I reinstall the Django in virtualenv cannot solve it.
It is the first time I ask question in here, also I'm not a native English speaker and just a python beginner. This task confused me for few hours and still found a solution. So I hopes someone can give me some advice. Thx.

​

Answer (score 0):

I am also an beginner and stucked by this issue. After long hours of battle i come to know the problem and solved it.
I am not sure it will work for you or not.
In your case please check out the following things:

1) Mainly this issue comes when javascript is not properly linked to file.
such as in my case stellar.js was not properly used or linked in html so browser throws "TypeError: stellar is not a function"

2) This also case of improper static_cdn file load of django. When you fire a command for "collectstatic" some times old files stays over there. First delete those files from static_cdn and fire command "collectstatic"

I hope this would help you

Comment: It means you solved the first case with the second suggetion?Can you tell me where to find the static_cdn?

Comment: 1) add root directory in settings such as  "STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")"

Comment: 2) Then add folder named as 'static_cdn' in project along side of template.  3) Paste all your static files such as css, java-script etc. in "static" directory. 4) Now fire command collectstatic, all the files get transferred to static_cdn. (But keep in mind cdn is used for quite differently even though the work looks simillar)

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work but still thx a lot. It's just weird because it happended not only in one virtualenv environment. If I create a new app this error also appears in admin page.